# In Python regexes, why can't I match 0-or-more, multiple times

Tags: python, regex

In Python, why does this bomb:

```
>>>re.compile(r'(?:.*){1}')
```

when this works

```
>>>re.compile(r'(?:.+){1}')
```

I just checked, in Perl, both work fine.  Now I don't like Perl.  I don't need Perl.  But this is a regular-expression engine question.  Why doesn't Python engine understand such a simple thing?

Comment: and why the downvote, care to explain?

Comment: Your first regex works fine for me. Please give an example that does not work!

Comment: No, it does not compile.

Comment: `>>> re.compile(r'(?:.*){1}')` → `<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x7fb878c31a48>`

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?  It compiles fine on 2.7.6 and on 3.4.1.  Could you please show the trace of it failing?

Comment: Yes I have 2.7.3.  I think this is the problem.

Comment: @MarkGaleck WHy did you use the quantifier `{1}` next to the non-capturing group?

Comment: Has nothing to do with non-capturing.  You use quantifiers to repeat things, whether you capture them or not.

Comment: @MarkGaleck what's the reason for adding quantifier to these regexes? I didn't find any difference between `.*`, `(?:.*){1}`, `(?:.*){2}`, etc. Note that these will decrease the performance even won't compile because of [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Comment: Not going to prove anything, but maybe the devs never wanted people to write a regex (a really bad one!!!) like that. You *can* repeat 'nothing' though, if you know what this 'nothing' could be more precisely (because what would be different between `(?:.*)` and `(?:.*)+` otherwise?), instead of leaving it as 'anything', see how [`(?:\S*\s*)+` compiles but `(?:.*)+` doesn't](http://codepad.org/eMA1KJBP).

Comment: @AvinashRaj the "reason" is that this is an SSCCE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These both work for me:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> p1 = re.compile(r'(?:.*){1}')
>>> m1 = p1.match("foo")
>>> m1.group()
'foo'
>>> p2 = re.compile(r'(?:.+){1}')
>>> m2 = p2.match("foo")
>>> m2.group()
'foo'
```

Comment: That's interesting!  Maybe this is fixed now.  I have 2.7.3.  Definitely the first one will not compile.

Comment: Indeed, it does not compile on 2.7.3

Comment: @JulienSpronck try `re.compile(r'(?:.*){1}+')`, possessive quantifier will completely avoid backtracking.

Comment: @AvinashRaj just tried, it gives me a 'mulitple repeat' error instead of 'nothing to repeat'

Answer (score 2):

The first regex is trying to repeat 1 instance of something which may not exist, hence an invalid regex.
The second one will always give a non-null string repeated once.

For example, in the first regex , it is not being checked how many times the null instance will be repeated, in the second it is, that is where it gives the error.

```
>>> re.compile(r'(?:.*)xyz')
<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x1a867b0>
>>> re.compile(r'(?:.*){1}')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 190, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 242, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat
```

Comment: I guess that is what I don't understand.  "May not exist" - no it does, in the parentheses there may be an empty string match, fine, I just want to repeat the empty string, so many times.  what's wrong with that.

Comment: how do you repeat an empty string?

Comment: what do you mean?  '' + '' + ''  and so forth

Comment: @DhruvPathak  I don't understand...  I just want the regex engine to do the match for .*, and I want to do it so many times (once).  What exactly is wrong with that?

Comment: @MarkGaleck When .* is empty, this means you want the regex engine to repeat empty many times ( once ). This behaviour was not allowed in regex engine of many versions of python . I am not sure about versions later than 2.7.3+ .

Answer (score 1):

Same reason why you can't do

```
re.compile(r'{1}')
```

There is or might be nothing to repeat once.

I think that the following regex should do the same as what you intended:

```
re.compile(r'((?:)|(?:.+){1})')
```

Comment: Pardon, but that is very much different, here there is nothing to repeat indeed.  But in my case, there is _nothing_repeated_ that is different.

Comment: @MarkGaleck: but with `*` there might be nothing repeated as well

Comment: that's why I wrote "there is OR might be" ... in this case, there is nothing to repeat ... in your case, there might be nothing to repeat

Comment: That's right, there is an empty string matched, and I want to repeat that .  What is wrong?  I am sorry, I just don't get it.  Works in Perl.  Why not here?

Comment: Yes indeed your second regex compiles.  But WHY go to all that extra trouble, with the alternative???  When the result is the same.

Comment: Sorry I don't know why.